# fragments in Thymeleaf

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I have created this fragment html page in Thymeleaf

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<ul th:fragment="top-menu" class="nav navbar-nav mai-top-nav">

    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link nav-link-selected" href="pages-my-ppt.html">My PPT</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="pages-all-ppt.html">All PPT</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="pages-my-wallets.html">Wallets</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="pages-purchases.html">Purchases</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="pages-alarms.html">Alarms</a></li>

</ul>

</html>
```

I use this fragment in another template:

```
 <ul th:replace="bonanza/common/top-menu :: top-menu" />
```

but I got this error message: `No end tag (</ul>).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap your ul fragment with a `<div>` and add `th:fragment` notation to that div.

For example:

```
<div th:fragment="top-menu">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav mai-top-nav">

    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link nav-link-selected" href="pages-my-ppt.html">My PPT</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="pages-all-ppt.html">All PPT</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="pages-my-wallets.html">Wallets</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="pages-purchases.html">Purchases</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="pages-alarms.html">Alarms</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

and use a div at another template:

```
<div th:replace="bonanza/common/top-menu :: top-menu"></div>
```

or you can just add a closing tag to your ul(but i am not sure with this, above is better)

```
<ul th:replace="bonanza/common/top-menu :: top-menu"></ul>
```